# How to solve this equation without drawing it's graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, radicals

I'm curious to know how can I solve this equation without drawing it's graph . Can we ever prove that the answer must be integer using number theory or other mathematical methods?  $$\sqrt{72-\frac{72}{x}}+\sqrt{x-\frac{72}{x}}=x$$ 
( the answer is $9$ )

Comment: Hint : Take the square on both sides, isolate the square root, and take the square again.

Comment: @Peter not a fast method . I'm talking about guessing the answer set ( x is integer or not )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with using numerical methods you can easily use the [fixed point iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) method to approximate the answer. Let,

$$f(x)=\sqrt{72 - \frac{72}{x}}  + \sqrt{x - \frac{72}{x}}$$

To have a real value for $x$ we should have,

$$\sqrt{72 - \frac{72}{x}}\geq 0\mbox{ and }\sqrt{x - \frac{72}{x}}\geq 0$$

Then,

$$x\geq 1  \mbox{ and }x^2\geq 72\Rightarrow x>8$$

$$\therefore x>8$$

Now choose as the initial point any number greater than $8$ and carry out the fixed point method. You will see that value of $x$ converges to $9$.